# What is the "conservative legal and judicial movement in the 1970s and 1980s" to which Justice Luttig refers?

Tags: united-states, history, conservatism

In CNN's March 5, 2024 [Retired federal judge blasts Supreme Court ruling: 'Stunning in its overreach'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4CThc7mfEo) retired federal Judge [J. Michael Luttig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Michael_Luttig) says the following (excerpted from YouTube auto-transcript with small edits):

> It's stunning in its overreach. It's a textbook example, Jake, of the kind of judicial activist, judicial opinion(s) from the 1960s and the warren court era **that begat the conservative legal and judicial movement in the 1970s and 1980s.** But of course, it's different here because this is unmistakably a conservative active court. most of whose members were leaders of that conservative movement, at least in the 1980s and forward.

**Question:** What is the "conservative legal and judicial movement in the 1970s and 1980s" to which Justice Luttig refers?

Was it an organized "movement"? Are there institutions existing and active today that have their roots in this movement?

Comment: companion question: [What exactly are the "stridencies" in the majority opinion on the Colorado ballot exclusion to which the two concurrencies refer?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/86120/16047)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federalist_Society